# Can I save my htc desire if the battery is dead?

Tags: htc-desire, battery, charging

I ran my HTC Desire on a 0% charged battery - and it shut it self down. Now it won't charge anymore and wont start even when plugged in.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options from my point of view:

- Buy a cheap replacement from ebay (search for 'BA-S410 HTC battery', the Nexus One also has the same battery)
- Leave it 'charging', maybe it revives on its own

Background:
LiIon batteries need a safety circuit because they must stay within certain charging levels (not under nor overcharged). If that circuit detects undercharge it may just think it's dead and prevent further charging for safety reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I'll try my luck with leaving it overnight in the outlet and see if it charges. 
Any idea if an external charger will be able to charge it?

Comment: Left it fro 6 hours ... didn't charge :(.
Now for eBay ...

Comment: Good news everyone! :) After taking out the SIM and re-inserting it (don't ask me why) - the device turned on. And to my surprise, the batter was 100% full now!

Answer (score 3):

How long have you left it charging for? If it hasn't been long (a couple of minutes then your phone is probably fine). Connect the phone to the mains and leave it plugged in (don't try to turn it on) for about 15 or 20 minutes. It should start up then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I tried it for about 20 min so far and I still don't see the charging light turning on. Should it turn on?